# -bash: aws: command not found on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to copy the file from S3 to EC2 when launching,

So, I put this command in `userdata`

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-admin-bk/gpumon.py gpumon.py
```

However, there is no aws in `EC2` as default.

How can I set up aws in `EC2`?

My `EC2` is in private subnet and no NatGateway (only VPC Endpoint)

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Launch userdata scripts are run as root. The awscli is pre-installed on most AWS-supplied AMIs, but only available on the PATH of the [default user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html#ami-default-user-names) for that AMI e.g. `ec2-user` for Amazon Linux and `ubuntu` for Ubuntu.

So, run your awscli command in userdata scripts as the correct user, e.g.

```
sudo -u ec2-user whoami
sudo -u ec2-user bash -c 'whoami;aws s3 cp s3://my-admin-bk/gpumon.py gpumon.py'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but I can't find aws-cli which is pre-installed.

Comment: If you SSH to your instance *after* launch, is `aws` on the default user's PATH? And is this Amazon Linux 2, Ubuntu, something else? Are you launching from a public AMI (which AMI id)?